# What is going on with the interweaving to cause this?

Tags: java, multithreading

Okay so I have two classes, Lock and Worker. 
All Lock does is create the Worker Object. Now in the Worker Two threads are going to run. I have created Objects to act as locks so that both threads can work on 1 of two methods at once instead both having to wait to use the shared intrinsic lock. All the methods do is add to 1 of two lists, going from 1 to 1000, so essentially both list1 and list will have(OR SHOULD) have 2000 number in the list.
What I want to understand is why does this give me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` during the process if I DON'T use the locks. All I am doing is adding to an arraylist, why is it going out of bounds? If both threads read the same size of the arraylist at the same time, does arraylist open up one spot while both threads are trying to place two numbers in at the same time? NOTE: If I uncomment the synchronized locks this works fine, I just want to know what's happening behind the scenes.

```
public class Lock     {
    public static void main(String[] args)        {
        Worker x = new Worker();
        try {
            x.main();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Worker {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();
    private List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void main() throws InterruptedException  {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                process();
            }
        });


        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                process();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time take: " +(end - start) + " ms");
        System.out.println("List1: " + list1.size() +"; List2: " + list2.size());
    }

    //Without synchronized it will not fill the entire list

    public void stageOne()  {
        //synchronized (lock1)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(InterruptedException e)                 {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            list1.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void stageTwo()      {
        //synchronized (lock2)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list2.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void process(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)  {
            stageOne();
            stageTwo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you sleep the thread for 1 millisecond?

Comment: Try the `Collections.synchronizedList()` method.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-

Comment: @mrres1 I honestly didn't have to I just did.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is not thread safe and without the `synchronized` blocks, both threads are adding elements in `list1` and later in `list2`.

What happens is probably that the backing array of one of the `ArrayList` reaches its full capacity and while it is being resized, one of the thread is trying to add an element to the already full array, thus throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to understand is why does this give me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` during the process if I DON'T use the locks.

We can't answer this exactly, we can only speculate. [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is not a thread-safe class. This is why you need to use synchronization.

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

If you don't use synchronization, things can blow up on you and in this case you have found that they do.

Speculating about what happens to cause this exception for this particular case isn't useful because it is essentially undefined. **It's important to understand that without synchronization the actions each thread takes with respect to one another have no specified order.** Therefore the sequence of events that cause the exception cannot be reasoned about in a logical manner.

For example, suppose `t1` takes two actions:

```
actionA();
actionB();
```

Without synchronization, `t2` is fully within its rights to see `actionB` but not `actionA`.

What definitely happens is the threads interleave at some point that causes one to attempt to access an index that is out of bounds. This is why synchronization is necessary.